# UWP Bindings in VisualState Setters

Tags: c#, uwp

Is it actually possible to use bindings with the Setters Value property in VisualState, because when I try to use x:Bind the initial view of the page is not using the bindings and with Binding the page does not use them ever or do I need to do something additional?

For example if I use the layout below and I start the app with a width between 400 - 800 the PassInput Passwordbox will not have a placeholder. When I resize the window to more than 800 and then back it will finally have the placeholder.

Example:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWP.Learning.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="Page">
    <RelativePanel Background="White">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowSizeStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="SmallState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="400" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="PassInput.PlaceholderText" Value="{x:Bind MyPlaceHolder, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="PassInput.PlaceholderText" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <TextBlock
            Name="PassLabel"
             RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
             RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
             RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
             Text="Pass input label"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <PasswordBox
             Name="PassInput"
             RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
             RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
             RelativePanel.Below="PassLabel"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Margin="20,0" />
    </RelativePanel>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace UWP.Learning
{
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage() { this.InitializeComponent(); }
        public string MyPlaceHolder => "FOOBAR";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. An easy workaround is to have a one-time check within the `Loaded` event.

```
Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    switch (ActualWidth)
    {
        case var w when (w >= 400 && w < 800):
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "SmallState", false);
            break;
        case var w when (w >= 800):
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "WideState", false);
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: So it seems and rather very annoying one, using XamlBehaviors for now to invoke a sort of refresh on the visual states and reported it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would call this a bug. For me it looks like this - the value of the setter is bound, not the PasswordBox.Placeholder, therefore if  we change the property and cal *OnPropertyCHanged*, nothing will happen, hence only setter's value will get affected. To see the change we have to invoke the visual state. The 'x:Bind' is being set-up in *Loading* event, then when the trigger is called for the first time, the binding is not ready and it crashes the trigger, you can check it - *WindowSizeStates.CurrentState* is *null*.

Comment: If you use old Binding and set FallbackValue, the you will see that it's used for the first time. With old Binding, you can call in Loaded event: `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, WindowSizeStates.CurrentState.Name, false);` and it should work, with new 'x:Bind' it cannot be used as binding hasn't resolved and *CurrentState* is null.

Comment: Yet shouldn't it already know what the CurrenState for WindowSizeStates should be and assign it, because if you add setters without any binding form above one that does they do get executed during loading.

Comment: @WaggaWagga The case is that if you use x:Bind, then when the trigger is being set when page is initialized, then binding cannot be resolved and crashes (?) the state manager - in result WindowSizeState is being null. On the other hand if you use old Binding with Fallback value, then the state is set correctly.

Comment: @Romasz you are absolutely right about it not being set because of the vsm is crashed. But the reason that I said it's bug is that, the initialisation of the size state should rely on the `SizeChanged` event, which happens *after* the `Loading` event, not some other hidden event that occurs before `Loading` (this hidden one also knows the initial size of the app even before `SizeChanged` is called which is interesting). Devs should really expect  `x:Bind` to just work.